# X, Y Animation Storyboard on button click for windows8 Apps

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winrt-xaml

I've spent about the entire day looking at examples of XAML storyboarding, but WinRT/Windows8 apps doesn't work the same way WPF does (At least I think), and I'm all confused.
All I want is a button that moves 100px left and 100px up when clicked. I'm having the hardest time figuring this out, and I know that once I get something I want working, I'll be able to work from there.

Also, if anyone can teach me how to use "Storyboard.TargetProperty" That'd be amazing.

```
 <Rectangle
  Name="Rectangle01"
  Height="100"
  Width="100"
  Fill="Red">
        <Rectangle.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="myboard">
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle01"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                From="100" To="3600" Duration="0:0:6" />
            </Storyboard>
            </Rectangle.Resources>
    </Rectangle>
```

Here's an example of something I tried doing just to mess around with storyboards. This didn't throw an error until I tried to execute it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, sorry amigo but SO isn't a code generator or a tutorial site. Instead I'd suggest sharing what you've tried and we can help fix it to save you the down-votes and getting your question closed. Oh, and using Blend generally makes doing storyboard work MUCH easier. Cheers

Comment: Added some sample code, not what I want, but I agree, that was wrong of me to simply demand code.

Comment: What error do you get with that code? Looks pretty reasonable to me...

Answer (score 1):

So yea, WRT is a little different in some ways, but many not.

What you're wanting to do is move your `Button` around, up and left so logically on an `X` and `Y` axis right? So in my mind, I think `RenderTransform`/`TranslateTransform` to leverage the `X` and `Y` like;

```
<Button Click="StartTheMove">
  <Button.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="MoveFoo"/>
  </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

So now we have `MoveFoo` and setup our Transform, and since the only default `Routed.Event` I know of for WRT is `Loaded` we can't do that, so tie into the Click handler with `StartTheMove` like;

```
private void StartTheMove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MoveTheButton.Begin();
}
```

So now we've got our handler and we want to fire off `MoveTheButton` which will be your actual storyboard set as a resource somewhere in say your window.resources or whatever like;

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MoveTheButton">
  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MoveFoo"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y">
    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.25" Value="100" />
  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MoveFoo"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.25" Value="-100" />
  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

So once we hit our `Storyboard` it's then going to go and tell our Transform that we want the properties of `X` and `Y` to get some new properties declared (here's your `Storyboard.TargetProperty` coming in to join the fun) and we're going to set the values to those two properties to something other than what they already are and basically tell it we want it to move 100px up on the `Y` (up) and -100px on the `X` (left) of our 2d axis. Which you'll also prob want to play with the keytimes for however fast/slow you want the effect to happen.

While I didn't have time to test this and am kind of just adhoc throwing it together before I leave the office for the day, we've all been where you are and hopefully it helps. You should also be able to add the interaction behaviors to kind of leverage the same type of event triggers you're probably more used to ([see tutorials](http://developer.sinnerschrader-mobile.com/windows-store-apps-invoke-triggeractions-in-xaml/492/)) and handle your event that way to ditch your handler code behind.

However hopefully this helps, if not I'll see it again in the morning and will take another stab at it. Cheers!

Comment: Sweet lord this was a HUGE help. I changed your default values of 100 to a "{Binding}" and gave them a name so I can determine where they're going to go using my codebehind (all of which I figured out after having this sample)! I could'nt have asked for more, you sir are amazing, thank you!

Comment: Cool deal, glad you found a remedy, if it answered your question please mark it as such for other potential viewers.